EF Core 6: How to select the latest element per group and cast to a different class
I have a table of Comments that has the following schema:
public Class Comments
{
    public string CommenterName { get; set; }
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public long ModificationTime { get; set; }
} 

I wish to create a query that gets the latest comment and Id out of a specific commenter on a given post.
I tried the following code:
Comment.Where(comment => comment.PostId == postId)
       .GroupBy(comment => new { comment.CommenterName }, comment => comment)
       .Select(comment => comment.OrderByDescending(i => i.ModificationTimeUnixTimeInMs).First())
       .Select(comment => new
                          {
                              Id = comment.Id,
                              Message = comment.Message
                          })
       .ToList()

The reason I want to do the last select is because the results are then added to a union with another query for pagination needs (the other query returns also Id & Message but from another table).
I am getting the following error:

The LINQ expression 'ProjectionBindingExpression: 0' could not be translated.

Can you please help me?
I am using .NET 6

What happens if you simplify to .GroupBy(comment => comment.CommenterName)

Still doesn't work sadly :(

How can ID and Message be from another table when you have them coming from comment?  Did you do a migration after making changes?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73591142/14868997 try doing moving that final Select before the GroupBy

Try following
Comment.OrderByDescending(i => i.ModificationTimeUnixTimeInMs)
       .GroupBy(comment => comment.CommenterName)
       .Select(x => x.First())
       .ToList();


This will get me the last result but will not project it to {Id, Message} like I need. It will get all the comments to the memory and then I will have to do it there

Great.  I fixed the error.  Do not understand why somebody gave me negative points.  You can add a Select to give only the id and message.

Hi, Sadly it is still not the answer..
If I do the select before the ToList I will get a projection exception.
If I do it after the ToList I would load all the columns into memory and then will do the casting. ince this table is very large I can have a OutOfMemory exception which I don't really want to happen

Change From : x.First() To : x.FirstOrDefault().  You may not be getting any results so FirstOrDefault() will remove the error.  You may have items without a CommenterName which is giving issues.

Still the same error :(
